# Pandas add column using groupby dataframe by sorting date column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/4/2021 8:17 |
| 1 | 5/25/2021 6:20 |
| 1 | 5/2/2021 22:15 |
| 2 | 7/12/2021 2:20 |
| 2 | 7/4/2021 21:28 |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |

For the repeating IDs, i want to sort the date from old to latest and then add a new column which marks increment index for that ID based on the date. And if there is no date for any ID, just add the first index.
Following is how I want my new dataframe to look like.

| ID | Date | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/2/2021 22:15 | 1 |
| 1 | 5/4/2021 8:17 | 2 |
| 1 | 5/25/2021 6:20 | 3 |
| 2 | 7/4/2021 2:20 | 1 |
| 2 | 7/12/2021 21:28 | 2 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |

Comment: Hello, Always share what all has been **tried** so far, this way contributors can pick from where you left off, instead of having to spend time preparing the inputs themselves.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).where(df['Date'].notna(), 1)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first and then [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set `1` if missing values in `Date`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'], ignore_index=True)

df['Index'] = np.where(df['Date'].notna(), df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1), 1)
print (df)
   ID                Date  Index
0   1 2021-05-02 22:15:00      1
1   1 2021-05-04 08:17:00      2
2   1 2021-05-25 06:20:00      3
3   2 2021-07-04 21:28:00      1
4   2 2021-07-12 02:20:00      2
5   2                 NaT      1
6   2                 NaT      1
```